# JSONPath expression chaining

Tags: javascript, object, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I'm trying on JSONPath expression on https://jsonpath.com.
I have the following JSON, and I only need the last **Order's** *(tranTxt)* **Invoice number** *(invcNr)*.
So first I filtered out the object where I have the status **Order**, then I wanted the get only the last Order's Invoice number.

This is the JSON:

```
[
    {
        "tranDt": "2022-06-15",
        "tranSeqNr": 676351522,
        "tranTxt": "Order",
        "invcNr": "73811514"
    },
    {
        "tranDt": "2022-06-30",
        "tranSeqNr": 710063627,
        "tranTxt": "Pending"
    },
    {
        "tranDt": "2022-08-11",
        "tranSeqNr": 795465799,
        "tranTxt": "Order",
        "invcNr": "73980890"
    },
    {
        "tranDt": "2022-08-17",
        "tranSeqNr": 806178419,
        "tranTxt": "Pending"
    }
]
```

My JSONPath:

```
$.[?(@.tranTxt=="Order")]
```

The result, is what I wanted:

```
[
  {
      "tranDt": "2022-06-15",
      "tranSeqNr": 676351522,
      "tranTxt": "Order",
      "invcNr": "73811514"
  },
  {
      "tranDt": "2022-08-11",
      "tranSeqNr": 795465799,
      "tranTxt": "Order",
      "invcNr": "73980890"
  }
]
```

And here I stucked, to get the last invoice no. **"invcNr": "73980890"**

I know that usually to use `$.[-1:]` I would get the last array element. But here is not helping.

I tried to use this JSONPath: `$.[?(@.tranTxt=="Order")].invcNr`
And the result is

```
[
  "73811514",
  "73980890"
]
```

So how can build the  `$.[-1:]` part into `$.[?(@.tranTxt=="Order")]` to receive the last order's invoice number?

Comment: You can't do it with one single `json-path-expression`. You have to do it in two steps where you provide the output of the first as an input to the second.

Answer (score 0):

What was working fine for me here is:

```
$..[-1:]
```

[image]

Or you can get your tranSeqNr as: `$..[-1:].tranSeqNr`

[image]

Or if you want to combine multiple:

```
$.[?(@.tranTxt=='Order' && @.tranSeqNr-1)].invcNr
```

you get:

```
[
  "73811514",
  "73980890"
]
```

Not sure this is what you need.